# How to read and store my name into smart card using java card? with example

Tags: javacard, contactless-smartcard

could some one tell me how to read and store my name in smart card using java card? i am using JCIDE 5.0

i want to know how to write program for read and store my name in javacard. Please help me out i am new to java card development

Answer (score 0):

You can write a specific applet in which you can store your name in a non-volatile memory.

Non-volatile memories are defined in your main class (which extend `Applet`) and initialized in your `constructor`. Methods for set and get your name should be implemented inside the `process` method.

As you `select` this applet, you are able to call the get method, whether you are in contact or contactless interfaces.

---

**Appendix 1:**

```
package pkgName;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class appName extends javacard.framework.Applet implements ExtendedLength {

private static final byte[] nameArr;

private appName(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    nameArr[] = new byte[128];
    register();
} // end of constructor

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    appName name = new appName(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
}

public boolean select() {}

public void deselect() {}

public void process(APDU apdu) {
    switch (ins) {
        case (byte) 0x01:
            set_name(apdu);
            break;
        case (byte) 0x02:
            get_name(apdu);
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
} // end of process method

private static void set_name(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    short len = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    Util.arrayCopy(buffer, (short) ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, nameArr, (short) 0, len);
    return;
}

private static void get_name(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    short len = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    Util.arrayCopy(nameArr, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, len);
    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, len);
    return;
}

} // end of class JAVA_APPLET
```

Comment: Could you write code for the above mentioned

Comment: @kusumabujji asking for code is against the rules, but you can see wallet example of oracle available in JCDK.

Comment: @kusumabujji this link can help: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-javame-downloads.html#javacarddevkitv212

Comment: If you download java card kit 2.2.1, in contains samples. there are examples were balance value is stored in non-volatile memory. You could instead store your name in a non-volatile byte array.

Comment: Tqs for the suggestion i tried to implement an applet but i couldn't that why i have asked

Comment: @bujji please check my answer again (Appendix 1)